# Arduino + WPA2-Enterprise

Tags: wifi, arduino, wireless, wpa

If anoyone has a link to a thread where someone has sucessfully connected an arduino to WPA2-Enterprise connection, PLEASE respond with a link.

Sparkfun's WiFly sheild manual http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/rn-131G-ds.pdf
mentions support for WPA2-Enterprise;

however, the "supported access points" portion of this [manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rovingnetworks.com%2Fresources%2Fdownload%2F93%2Fwifly_user_manual&ei=Xbh_UJmfLYO-yQGs64D4DA&usg=AFQjCNFkOVaKF1DKAvVrVcWDUThMJCeSHg&sig2=5IK5el5V6-8QWkKY0aMCwA) says it does not

So which is it. Can it be done? How can I connect my arduino to a WPA2-Enterprise Connection? Please help. I'm willing to buy a new shield, but I'm looking for a thread showing that it has been done with that hardware.

Comment: For what it is worth, the latest firmware (v4.0) includes an "Enterprise Security App (BETA)", whatever that means. Maybe it does what you want. Check it out: http://www.rovingnetworks.com/WiFly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a WiFly shield and I didn't succed into connecting it with WPA2 Enterprise, but it works fine on WEP.

Comment: You might be interested in my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950031/arduino-wpa2-enterprise#comment25815895_12950031 :)